# Using handler postdelay for running a code periodically

Tags: android, handler

I want to log a message periodically in every 60 seconds. I think I should use handler with postdelayed method. However methods that suggested in other questions doesn work for me.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHandler=new DatabaseHandler(this);
    data = dbHandler.fetchAllItemsIn(5);
   run= new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String items="";
            for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
                items+=data.get(i).getItemName()+"\n";
            }
            Log.d("items:",items);
        }
    };

}
public void LogDatabase(View view){
  Handler hand=new Handler();

  hand.postDelayed(run,60);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `TimerTask`? check it out: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work for you because you run your `Runnable` only once.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHandler=new DatabaseHandler(this);
    data = dbHandler.fetchAllItemsIn(5);
    hand = new Handler();

    run= new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String items="";
            for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
                items+=data.get(i).getItemName()+"\n";
            }
            Log.d("items:",items);
            hand.postDelayed(run,60);
        }
    };

}
public void LogDatabase(View view){
  hand.postDelayed(run,60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not only want a single execution - you need to call postDelayed at the end of your runnable again